# How do I display an article using a WordPress custom field?

Tags: custom-field, get-posts

I want to display 3 articles with specific custom fields on the front page. The article needs to contain "featured" fields and the value is true.

If the article does not exist, 3 random articles are displayed.

Can this function be implemented?

Comment: Yes, sure it can. But you could also use Tag or Category than custom field.

Comment: What do I need to do? There is a downside to using tags and categories, which adds a publicly accessible archive link.

Comment: There are actually filters/hooks you can use to exclude certain terms from the public, including restricting access to a specific term's archive page. Nonetheless, see my answer for retrieving and displaying the featured posts *by custom field*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, and you can use the `meta_key` along with `meta_value` parameter. Secondly, you're going to need two queries when there are no featured posts:

1. Query the featured articles/posts:

   ```
   $q = new WP_Query( [
       'post_type'      => 'post',
       'meta_key'       => 'featured',
       'meta_value'     => '1',
       'posts_per_page' => 3,
       'no_found_rows'  => true,
   ] );
   ```
2. Query random posts:

   ```
   $q = new WP_Query( [
       'post_type'      => 'post',
       'orderby'        => 'rand',
       'posts_per_page' => 3,
       'no_found_rows'  => true,
   ] );
   ```

Here's an example:

```
$q = new WP_Query( [
    'post_type'      => 'post',
    'meta_key'       => 'featured',
    'meta_value'     => '1',
    'posts_per_page' => 3,
    'no_found_rows'  => true,
] );

// No featured posts.
if ( ! $q->have_posts() ) {
    $q = new WP_Query( [
        'post_type'      => 'post',
        'orderby'        => 'rand',
        'posts_per_page' => 3,
        'no_found_rows'  => true,
    ] );
    echo 'Displaying random posts.'; // test
} else {
    echo 'Displaying featured posts.'; // test
}

if ( $q->have_posts() ) {
    while ( $q->have_posts() ) {
        $q->the_post();

        // Display the post.
        the_title( '<h3>', '</h3>' );
        //...
    }
}
```

PS: When pagination is not needed, you should always set the `no_found_rows` to `true`. Also, I'm assuming you'd use the standard custom fields editor or a plugin like ACF, to add/manage the custom field to/for your posts.

Comment: Thank for your answer!

Comment: No problem, @Matthew. And if you need (further) help with any of the query parameters I used in the answer, see [this](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/parse_query/#parameters).